# How can i make for loop in cat shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to python and shell , I need to for loop on this statement

```
cat $input | sst print-vectors $model_bin_file > tors.txt
```

which `$input` here is a file contain `one line` , How can i make it loop for all lines in the file in one statement ? The file i have that contains all lines called `out.txt`

I tried to write

```
for i in $(cat $out.txt | sst print-tors $model_bin_file)
do 
 i> tors.txt
done
```

i got `i: not found`

Comment: For each line in the file `vectors.txt` you want to run `fasttext print-vectors $model_bin_file`?

Comment: Refer my update below, I think you need the `>>` append operator, to append lines to `vectors.txt`

Comment: Does the content of line matters for `fasttext print-vectors $model_bin_file`? Or simply you want to run `fasttext print-vectors $model_bin_file` N number of times, where N = number of lines in out.txt file?

Comment: yes i need to run this command for out.txt simply

Comment: Means simply N number of times?

Comment: N here will depeend on number of lines out.txt has

Comment: @Inian excuse me , i didn't get what do you mean ?

Comment: Can you explain more on `which $input here is a file contain one line , How can i make it loop for all lines in the file in one statement ? The file i have that contains all lines called out.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a proper loop, see why you [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and how to avoid useless-use-of-cat

```
 #!/bin/bash
 while IFS= read -r line
 do
     # do whatever you want to do with the line read stored as "$line"
     echo "$line" | ass print-tors "$model_bin_file"
 done <"out.txt"  >> "tors.txt"
```

Comment: it still working , i will know if it will work successfully after finish then i will tell you

Comment: @downvoter: Care to explain why you did it? Rationale behind it?